# how to show login error if i type a wrong password that was not saved in my mysql database?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

how to show login error if i type a wrong password that was not saved in my mysql database?

```
try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/" + sdbName,"root","");
stmt = con.createStatement();
session.putValue("CONN",con);
session.putValue("STMT",stmt);

rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select count from users1 where pword='" + spword + "' and uname='"+suname+"'");
if(rsT.next())
{

String result = rsT.getString(1);
}
rsT.close();

if(errFlag)
{
%> <%=str%> <%
return;
}
stmt = null;
con = null;
rsT = null;
}
catch(SQLException sqle)
{
str = "<h2>Error : " + sqle + "</h2>";
errFlag = true;
}
%>
```

how to show login error if i type a wrong password that was not saved in my mysql database?
I would like to display the alert message when the error user id and password was typed in textbox

Answer (score 0):

Few pointers:

(1) Normally, you don't want to save the passwords in the DB.

You want to save their only a hashcode produced from the password.
For example every time you get the password you convert it to sha256 or something like that and then you work with that 'sha256 password'.
Java has digest api and can do the sha encoding for you.
Example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sha-256-hash-in-java/

(2) You don't want to have code like that:

```
rsT = stmt.executeQuery("select count from users1 where pword='" + spword + "' and uname='"+suname+"'");
```

The code above is very susceptive to injection attacks. You want to leverage the java prepared statements and inject the parameters into it and make your query look like that:

```
 "select count from users1 where pword=? and uname=?"
```

Example: https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface

I hope all that helps you and good luck in you efforts